# changing thumbnails of profiles in mass in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$l = import-csv -path "C:\art1\user.csv"

Foreach ($name in $l)
    {
        $photo = [byte[]](Get-Content "C:\Art\rem\$name.jpg" -Encoding byte) 
        Set-ADUser $name -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$photo}
    }
```

I was trying to import mass thumbnail images to active directory profiles. but the above code keeps throwing an error.

Can anyone please help and let me know where I am going wrong?

> Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Art\rem\@{xxx.abc=yyy.abc}.jpg' because it does not exist.
>   At X:\NewUser\ProfilePic.ps1:5 char:31
>   + ...  $photo = [byte[]](Get-Content "C:\Art\rem\$name.jpg" -Encoding byte)
>   +                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Art\rem\@{xxx.abc=yyy.abc}.jpg:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: `$name` is the object, not a string. You need to either specify header for the `.csv` (and then use `$($name.headerName)` or (even better) access data using `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

`@{xxx.abc=yyy.abc}` indicates that the error is with the structure of your data. Due to the fact that you use `Import-Csv` PowerShell interpretes first line of your file (which is `xxx.abc`) as a header.

You need to make sure that you're using proper command for the format of data you have. If you want it to be `.csv`, first line should be header name (let's take `fullname` as an example). In this case you'd access your data by using `$($name.fullname)`.

### Solution:

The more suitable and quick solution would be just to use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I will now give you the way I do it in my environment.

```
# Set the network path of the user pictures.
$NetworkPath = "\\FileServer\UserPictures"

# Get all the filesnames without the extension, every picture inside this folder should be named after the username of the user.
$UsersNames = Get-ChildItem -Path "$NetworkPath"| % {$_.BaseName}

# For each file name (username) go and convert into digital (byte encoding) the file then store it in a temporary value ($Photo).
# Then update the users jpegPhoto attribute on Active Directory with the $photo
foreach ($User in $UsersNames){
    $Photo = [Byte[]](Get-Content "$NetworkPath\$User.jpg" -Encoding Byte)
    Set-ADUser $User -Replace @{jpegPhoto=$Photo}
}
```

Sorry for my previous reply, it was a mistake to not sit down and write a proper answer.
Thank you guys for the comments.

Comment: Just a heads up re this: `"C:\TempFolder\$User.Name.jpg"` - you cannot access property of `$User` like this.

Comment: Note that this would throw tons of errors if there are users in your AD without a matching .jpg  file.

Comment: Like @robdy said, it should be `"C:\TempFolder\$($User.Name).jpg"` instead.

Comment: Sorry guys! Yes this one will throw a tone of errors you are right like @robdy said you must have it like $($User.Name).jpg. As for the users not having a picture you fan put an If with condition of check the name of the user -eq the name of the pic. I will update my answer.